# Calculating projectile path when fired at an angle, forward

Tags: path, projectile

I have a problem to code the path of a projectile from a gun as it moves forward and upward. This needs to be done in p5.js.

Although the Angry Birds method has been tried by me, I am looking for a more physics derived function involving the sine and cosine of angle of the gun.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you started by reading our extensive library of [existing Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=projectile%20angle) on [projectile-physics](/questions/tagged/projectile-physics), and [constructing a vector from an angle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=vector%20angle).

Putting those together, you should have no difficulty deriving:

```
launchVelocity.x = launchSpeed * Math.cos(launchAngle);
launchVelocity.y = launchSpeed * Math.sin(launchAngle);

positionAtTimeT.x = launchPosition.x + t * launchVelocity.x
positionAtTimeT.y = launchPosition.y + t * launchVelocity.y + t * t * gravity/2.0;
```

Where `gravity` is your acceleration due to gravity, eg. \$-9.81 \frac m {s^2}\$